Using templates without generic implementation
Is it a good practice to declare a template class, but only with specialized implementations ?
Ie, there are many CRC flavours (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check#Polynomial_representations), but not a generic one.
It could make sense to declare a CRC class with two template parameters : the CRC size, and a policy class, as :
template<Size, Flavour>
class CRC;

template<>
CRC<16,IBM>
{
...
};

I could have a class CRC16IBM, but it appears to me less readable than CRC<16,IBM>. Also, I guess I could factorize some code for all CRC implementations on 16 bits.

You can also create an alias for it. using CRC16IBM = CRC<16, IBM>;. It is common-place in the STL (e.g., using string = basic_string<char>;)


Is it a good practice to declare a template class, but only with specialized implementations ?

That should not be a problem. The C++ standard even has it in several places, like std::numeric_limits<>.

Quite a few places, iirc all of the std::foo_traits<> templates are only complete types in specialisations
